# How to flash factory firmware on Motorola Moto G 2015 XT1550

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, device-firmware

I am currently using Motorola Moto G 2015, that is Moto G third generation smart phone. (XT1550)
I updated android 6.0 .
But it's not that much of great. 
So I tried to flash factory firmware which is android 5.1.1, referred from  [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/index-moto-g-factory-firmware-images-t3169639).
But after installation also I am getting android 6.0 itself.

I want to flash factory firmware. That is android 5.1.1

> Without rooting my phone can I flash factory firmware ?

Comment: Yes, you can flash the firmware **without** root using ADB and fastboot.

Comment: I tried twice through ADB and fastboot by downloading the proper indian version of firmware and mfastboot. But after the installation firmware will not change.

Comment: So what's your problem here? You write you got "Android 5.1.1", but you wanted "Android 5.1.1". Isn't that the same, or do I miss something here? Maybe a mis-typing, and you got 6.0 again? Which would be understandable, as the manufacturer will have provided the latest version for download. In that case, check the download page for "previous" or "older" versions, and see if you can find 5.1.1.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question. After release of android 6.0, I updated and It's not good. So I want to flash factory firmware which is 5.1.1 . So I downloaded proper firmware from xda-developers website. And i tried to flash using ADB commands. It will show flashing /writing system and all those things. and after the reboot firmware willl not change. I mean it will be the same android 6.0 .

Comment: @VTVishwanathBhat then your doing it wrong. Perhaps you should read the dozen or so threads on XDA (where you got the software) about downgrading... There is a very specific procedure which must be followed, factory reset, flash every piece except gpt.bin, and I believe to downgrade you must have an unlocked bootloader. And after downgrade you must never take an OTA update... It's all clearly spelled out on XDA

Comment: Then I can't downgrade without unlocking bootloader, right ?

Comment: Actually I want to downgrade without voiding the warranty. And I tried the steps to flash stock ROM without unlocking the bootloader.